# Active admin override action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to override my `update` action in all my controllers.

Is it possible to do in one place, not in each controller separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a module that overrides the action, and then include in in `initializers/active_admin.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.before_load do |_app|
  ActiveAdmin::BaseController.send :include, your-module-here
end
```